How come I can't get the screen size and color to change
# Set the output screen size and color
cmd = 'color 1F'   
cmd = 'mode 200,30'  
os.system(cmd)    

it only takes the cmd right before os.system(cmd).
If I move cmd = 'color 1F' down then it changes the color of the screen but will not resize.

That's because the second assignment to cmd overwrites the first one.

I'm not sure but you may use ; to run two commands cmd = 'color 1F ; mode 200,30'

If you want to run both commands, then you need to call os.system() twice:
cmd = 'color 1F'
os.system(cmd)
   
cmd = 'mode 200,30'  
os.system(cmd)

